# Jenkins does not use system's locales

Tags: shell, ubuntu, locale, bashrc, jenkins

I got a interesting behavior in Jenkins.
Jenkins' shell does not use my systems locales.

Jenkins runs as user `jenkins` on my system.

#### Logged in as `jenkins` via SSH:

`locale` displayed:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   LANGUAGE=en_US:en
>   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   etc...

`env` shows `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` variables:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   LANGUAGE=en_US:en

`id` shows the ID of user:

> uid=1008(jenkins) gid=...

#### Entered above commands to a jenkins job shell:

`locale` displayed:

> LANG=
>   LANGUAGE=
>   LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
>   etc...

`env` does **not** show `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` variables

`id` shows the ID of user (as expected):

> uid=1008(jenkins) gid=...

#### the files:

`/etc/profile` contains:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   export LANGUAGE=en_US:en

`/etc/default/locale` contains:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   export LANGUAGE=en_US:en

startup script `/etc/init.d/jenkins` should export system's locales:

> # load environments
>   if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
>    . /etc/default/locale
>    export LANG LANGUAGE
>   elif [ -r /etc/environment ]; then
>    . /etc/environment
>    export LANG LANGUAGE
>   fi

Of course I rebooted after modifying the locales ;)

Apache also uses the system's locales
My system is an Ubuntu 14.04 installation.
Did I miss to check something else?

Thank you for reading!
I hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Jenkins seems to reset all environment variables in build shells. Check the project settings. There is also an [env-inject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Comment: Your solution should be an answer, not an edit to your question...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solution:

This happens because the Jenkins master connects to the slave machine via `non-interactive` shell, so `/etc/profile` is not executed, and also `/etc/default/locale` does not have any effect.
`non-interactive` shells are usually using `~/.bashrc`. 

Nearly all details about this topic can be found on askubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells

adding to `~/.bashrc`:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   export LANGUAGE=en_US:en

did it for me.

This 'slave problem' is also discussed here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/hscDs4pKIoU
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/g0fNnDltqeM
Kind regards, whosit